# Laravel /installed.json does not contain valid JSON

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

So I have had this error once before and I do not remember what I have done to fix it. I also have checked all the solutions online I could find, but no success.

I have installed a fresh copy of laravel and I have no changed a thing, other than added some views and routes, nothing fancy.

When trying to do `composer update` I got this error, as seen in the image:

[image: error message]

So I removed my vendor folder and tried to do `composer install`, which results in the same error as below (this is where the above screenshot is from, not from the `composer update` error, although it is the same).

My composer.json file is below, I have not touched this:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.75",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.4",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.10",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.5.10"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Some info about which versions I am running:

```
laravel/homestead (hyperv, 9.1.1)
laravel/homestead (virtualbox, 9.2.2-alpha1)
PHP 7.4.1 (cli) (built: Dec 18 2019 14:44:22) ( NTS )
```

Any ideas as to what might be wrong?

Comment: Can you check if the PHP's JSON extension is installed and enabled, with `phpinfo()`? The only reason I can think of for this file to be empty on a clean install is if json_encode isn't working properly

Comment: Thanks for your comment, all good there. Still no fix after trying a lot of stuff, updating vagrant, homestead, etc.. So installed a new, fresh copy of laravel again, checked the installed.json file, seems all good, not empty. Did a `composer update` and voila, works. So right now I will keep an eye on what I change and see if I can duplicate the issue or if this was just an incident

Comment: compare: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/3786

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fresh installation of Laravel did the trick, not been able to figure out what the actual issue was.